# Что такое дыбленый крест?

Tags: значение-слов

> То надобно на семи безымянных могилах с крестами дыблеными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Незаконченное предложение, думаю, взято [отсюда](https://chernayamagiya.com/forum/index.php?topic=9241.0) (орфография и пунктуация сохранены):

> То надобно на семи безымянных могилах с крестами дыблеными.да на каждой могиле то по лоскуту закопать.коль закапываетсья,то надобно узелок на лоскутне завязать. то сказать.

В этимологическом словаре Тимофеева нашлось вот что (даю полностью — вдруг у кого-то ссылка не откроется):
[***Дебелый***](http://www.tezan.ru/slov_etym_5.htm)

> *«ДЕБЕЛЫЙ, матерый, толстый, плотный, здоровый, гладкой, тучный. Дебелый скот. Дебелая стена. арх. капитальная, бревенчатая внутри дома, не перегородка. Дебелая буква, дебелое произношенье, твердое, густое, толстое. Буква ъ дает дебелый, ь - мягкий выговор. Дебелость, качество это, толстота, плотность, тучность. Дебелеть, плотнеть, тучнеть, толстеть.»* **[СД]**
> *«Родственно др.-прусск. debīkan "большой", возм., также д.-в.-н. tapfar "тяжелый", ср.-в.-н. tapfer, др.-исл. dapr "тяжелый, мрачный, скорбный" (Бернекер 1, 182; Бецценбергер, GGA, 1898, 554; Траутман, Apr. Sprd. 318; BSW 47; Младенов 122; Торп 200). Привлеченное Бернекером (там же) лтш. dabl̨š, dābls "пышный, разросшийся" относится к до́ба, до́брый (М. – Э. 1, 428). Ср. до́блесть.»* **[СФ]**
> *«От ар.* **دبل** *дабила "быть жирным". (М., стр. 206).»* **[ЭCВ]**
> Неверно от «доба» - пора, время (др.-слав.).
> *«ДОБОЛЫЙ сиб. дебелый, крепкий, дюжий, плотный, здоровый.»* **[СД]**
> Дебелый от доболый, далее «добрый», иначе, здоровый, тучный
> Дебелый – debelij > dobolij > dobrij – ***добрый*** (слав.)(редукция r/l)
> Но, возможно, и от «лебедий», с дыбленой грудью.
> Дебелый – debelij > diblenij/lebedij - ***дыбленый/лебедий*** (слав.)
> Корневое слово от «дебелый» - ***добрый*** / ***дыбленый***/***лебедий*** (слав.)

В этимологическом словаре Фасмера — вот что:
[ды́бить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (дыбленный):

> От дыба, далее из др.-русск. дыба (грам. 1229 г.), ды́бом (от *дыбъ м.), дыбы́, дыба́ть «стоять на кончиках пальцев», укр. ди́бки-ди́бки «пляска вприпрыжку», укр. диба́ти «семенить», польск. dyba «позорный столб, колода», н.-луж. dybnuś «встретить». Возможно родственно др.-сканд. toppr «конец, коса (волосы)», др.-англ. topp «верхушка, макушка», др.-в.-нем. zopf «коса (волосы)».

В первом случае можно предположить, что крест должен быть крупным: массивным, добротным — не маленьким (такие раньше ставились на детских могилках).

Во втором случае можно думать, что крест должен быть обязательно стоящим, вертикальным.
Кресты на безымянных могилах (обычно это такие, за которыми никто не ухаживает) могут упасть со временем, особенно деревянные.

Или могут подразумеваться настолько старые надгробия, у которых надписи на кресте, табличке или камне стерлись.
Есть, кстати, и могилы, оформленные с крестом, *лежащим* на поверхности.

В итоге — представляю себе, что речь, возможно,  идет о больших безымянных крестах, которые стоят.

Answer (score 1):

В «Корнеслове русского языка» Ф. Шимкевича в одном из значений *дыба* есть столб (с. 71). Вероятно, что речь идёт не о врытых в землю крестах, а о крестах, укреплённых с некоторым отрывом от грунта из соображений их лучшей сохранности.